# How to use list ordered and unordered in Google Colab?

Tags: python, html, google-colaboratory

I want to format my text in Google Colab, in the form of a list and I want to use an ordered and unorder lists as well.
Also please suggest some ideas to best format text in Google Colab.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/markdown_guide.ipynb#scrollTo=HSYswUKFw3FL

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create an unordered list, you add a * in the beginning and it creates a bullet list. More options on the link below tho!

For a normal ordered list use the `<ol>` tag and for the list contents use the `<li>`  tag. Inside the `<ol>` tag you can select the type you want by adding it as a string to `type=`. I think the options are 1, A, a, I and i.

If you check the link below you’ve got more info on this: https://colab.research.google.com/github/Tanu-N-Prabhu/Python/blob/master/Cheat_sheet_for_Google_Colab.ipynb#scrollTo=zKimFHlT05w_